# Sum 5 lines of the max values in a column and get the % in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with some contracts, like this:

| Contract Num | Another header | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | Cleaning | 123.541,00-- |
| 544311 | Security | 200.000,00-- |
| 254856 | Cleaning | 23.581,00-- |
| 048941 | Security | 80.000,00-- |
| 128546 | Cleaning | 300.500,00-- |
| 255311 | Security | 99.000,00-- |
| 130056 | Cleaning | 543.541,00-- |
| 859311 | Security | 10.000,00-- |

I want to get this in Power Bi:

1. The value of the 5 most expensive contracts
2. How much these 5 represents in % of the total sum.

I got the letter A in a card applying filters (N Superior), but I can't work with it in a measure. What expression can I use to get a number of line in a column? How can I solve this in a measure?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Please test this DAX Code:

This gives you the TOP5 Total:

```
Top5_Total =
VAR TOP5Total =
    SUMX ( TOPN ( 5, YourTable, [Value] ), [Value] )
RETURN
    TOP5Total
```

And This gives you the ratio of Top5 To All Totals:

```
RatioOfTop5_To_Total =
VAR TOP5Total =
    SUMX ( TOPN ( 5, YourTable, [Value] ), [Value] )
VAR Total =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( YourTable[Value] ), ALL ( YourTable ) )
VAR PercentOfTop5_To_Total =
    DIVIDE ( 100 * TOP5Total, Total )
RETURN
    PercentOfTop5_To_Total
```

Comment: You're welcome. I am pleased that your problem is solved.